# Ayuda en Python, time.sleep() o Event().wait()

Tags: python

Estoy usando la biblioteca **vlc** para un reproductor de música donde creé la ventana con **pyqt5**. Lo que intento hacer es reproducir una lista propia que creo guardando los datos y path en una **sqlite3**. Para ello intento mediante hilos que se reproduzcan los temas. El problema es que deseo en algunos casos terminar el mp3 que se está reproduciendo antes de tiempo, y en simultáneo reproducir el siguiente mp3. Entonces intenté demorar la 2da reproducción con `time.sleep()` y con `Event().wait()`, pero en ambos casos, me congelan la ventana principal *(la que hice en pyqt5)* hasta que dicho tiempo no se termina.

Subo el código simplificado, porque lo demás funciona, con éste código se puede ver el mismo problema de todas formas, y le coloco sólo una demora de 5 segundos para probarlo, pero en realidad los datos los tengo en la base de datos en sqlite3:

```
import sys
import time
import threading
from threading import Event

import vlc
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
#from PyQt5 import *
#Módulo de PyQt5 que interpreta los archivos .ui generados por PyQt5, sino, deberíamos convertir dichos archivos
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class Ventana_Reproductor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ventana_Reproductor, self).__init__()
        loadUi('Ventana_Reproductor.ui', self)
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.Reproduce)

    def Reproduce(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.Reproduce2('1.mp3', 0))
        t1.start
        t2 = threading.Thread(target = self.Reproduce2('2.mp3', 5))
        t2.start

    def Reproduce2(self, Archivo, Demora):
        #time.sleep(Demora)
        Event().wait(Demora)
        instance = vlc.Instance()
        player = instance.media_player_new()
        media = instance.media_new('D:\\Programación\\Python\\Proyectos\\Reproductor\\' + Archivo)
        player.set_media(media)
        player.play()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
_ventana = Ventana_Reproductor()
_ventana.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo con:
*threading.Timer(10.0, self.Reproduce2).start()*

Donde 10.0 puede ser una variable flotante y es el tiempo que se va a demorar en ejecutar la función que está a continuación, y que en éste caso es self.Reproduce2.

De todas maneras no quedo conforme porque ahora tengo 2 problemas aunque ya están solucionados, y el primero es que la función a la que llamo, no le puedo pasar argumentos porque me genera error, y he intentado con: *threading.Timer(10.0, self.Reproduce2('1.mp3')).start()* y también con: *threading.Timer(10.0, self.Reproduce2, args = '1.mp3').start()*. Por ello es que me encargo de obtener los datos que necesito dentro de la función que es llamada. Cabe aclarar que integrando el Timer en el llamado a la función, el parámetro "demora" fue eliminado quedando únicamente el de "Archivo".

Y la segunda es que si por ejemplo deseamos cerrar el programa cerrando la ventana principal, el hilo que está en espera se va a ejecutar igual, que en éste caso es la reproducción de un mp3, por ende, tuve que agregar una variable global que le indique a la función que si dicha variable está en "False", entonces termina sin ejecutar nada. También estuve investigando si se podía abortar el hilo y dicha función existe (sería por ej: *"Th1.abort()"*), pero parece ser que genera comportamientos inesperados en el programa y por lo general recomiendan evitarlo, y por el contrario encontré una solución que publican explicando que se cambia el valor del tiempo de espera a un infinito, aún así, yo prefiero que se ejecute la función original y termine sin dar ningún tipo de resultados.

Como conclusión, el problema principal solucionado y los 2 que surgieron luego también solucionados aunque tal vez tengan mejores opciones para hacerlo.